# Não consigo mostra o erro em minha view

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, knockoutjs

Bom, tenho uma view e não consigo mostrar as mensagem de erro, o código esta bem grande e coloque de uma forma resumida mas precisa de alguma parte eu vou editando.

Controller Antes estavá assim:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  return PartialView("InternalAuditRecordForm", criticalAnalysisRecord);
}
```

Imagem de quando o knockoutjs para de funcionar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora está assim:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  ModelState.OrderByKeys(criticalAnalysisRecord.GetValidationOrder());
  Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
  return Json(ModelState.GetModelStateErros());
}
```

Imagem do knockoutjs funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O javaScript:

```
function saveInternalAuditRecord() {
            removeAllPlaceHolder();
            clearErrorsMessages();
            responsibles = "";
            $("select#Responsibles option").each(function () {
                responsibles += $(this).val() + ",";
            });
            auditors = "";
            $("select#Auditors option").each(function () {
                auditors += $(this).val() + ",";
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "/InternalAuditRecord/SaveInternalAuditRecord",
                type: "post",
                data: $("form#internalAuditRecordRegisterForm").serialize()+"&idResponsibles="+responsibles+"&idAuditors="+auditors,
                success: function (res) {
                    if (typeof (res) == "object") {
                        if (res.success) {
                            window.location.replace("/InternalAuditRecord/InternalAuditRecord");
                        }
                        else {
                            flashMessage();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $("article.container_12").replaceWith(res);

                        validationCheckImage("#Name", "#span_location");
                        //$("#Name").addClass("input-validation-error");

                        loadSwitches();
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
                    }
                }, error: function () {
                    $("#messages").html("<p class=\"message error no-margin\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px !important;\">Ocorreu um erro durante a gravação dos dados.</p>");
                }

            });
        }
```

meu Entitie:

```
public class InternalAuditRecord
    {
        [Key]
        public int InternalAuditRecordID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo \"Descrição\" deve ser preenchido")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

E a DIV na view:

```
 <div id="messages">
     <div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Desta forma ele traz o erro porém o knockoutjs para de funcionar, com o formato antigo do controller.
Agora o novo o knockoutjs continua funcionando mas não consigo exibir o erro na minha view.